# Lint reports StringBuilder affects performance

Tags: android, performance, lint

on my Project i just did a LINT check, so far im happy with it. But im curious why LINT reports that the usage of StringBuilder is slow ?

I switched from Eclipse to Android Studio a while ago, those toString() methods where generated by eclipse to get some better debugging output:

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("param1");
    builder.append(param1);
    builder.append(", param2");
    builder.append(param2);
    builder.append("param3");
            ....
    return builder.toString();
}
```

In Studio its reported 'replace StringBuilder with String'. From my perspective an StringBuilder was always the faster and more GC friendly approach. Or does DEX something clever there alreasy i dont know ?

I searched [LINT Checks](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) without any description on that

Comment: Worth pointing out that GC is reliable enough to mean that differentiating between the two is probably useless. If you were to be swapping between high res images or something, GC might become more of a factor, but for creating a String you should not be worrying about GC or the speed of the String's creation. It is minuscule when compared to other functionality in your application

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that while there is absolutely no difference in performance whatsoever but it is easier to do:

```
String string = "param1" + param1 + ", param 2" + param2 + "param3".... (and so on)
```

I would prefer this approach simply because it is shorter. Behind the scenes the compiler will convert it to the code you just mentioned and the bytecode generated is exactly the same.

If you are building the string within a loop, then a StringBuilder is definitely the way to go.

Comment: theres still the question why LINT says its bad ?

Comment: In my opinion LINT still needs some features ironed out. It is still quite generic in the manner in which it analyzes your code which is why they allow you to customize it to exclude some checks. A generic analysis would probably assume that concatenating using String might result in smaller code than appending using StringBuilder.

Comment: Even that is is wrong on a normal JVM as Strings gets concatenate using StringBuilder which should result in same size of bytecode